# NLP to match with previous requests

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, doc2vec

I am working on a requirement where I have history of previous requests. Requests may be like "Send me a report of .." or "Get me this doc" and this will get assigned to some one and that person will respond.

I need to build an app which will analyse the previous request and if a new request arrives and if any of the previous requests matches then I should recommend the previous request's solution.

I am trying to implement the above using Python and after some research I found doc2vector is one of the approach to convert the previous requests to a vector and match with vector of new request. I want to know, is this the right approach or are better approaches available?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different approaches for your problem. Actually, there's no right or wrong answer, but the one that fits your data, objectives and expected results more properly. To mention a few:

**Vectorization (doc2vec)**

This approach will make a vector representation of a document based on individual words vector from a pretrained source (these so called embeddings can be more general with worse results in too closed contexts or more specific, being better fit to a special type of text).

In order to match a new request to this vector representation of your document, the new request have to share words with a closely related vector representation, otherwise it won't work.

**Keyword matching (or topicalization)**

A simpler approach, where a document is classified by the more representative keywords in it (using techniques such as [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) or even simpler word distribution).

To match a new request, this has to include the keywords of the document.

**Graph Based Approach**

I've worked with this approach for Question Answering in my Master's research. In it, each document is modeled as a graph node connected to its keywords (which are also nodes). Each word in the graph is related to other words and compose a network through which the document is accessed.

To match a new request, the keywords from the request are retrieved and "spread" using one of many network traversal techniques, attempting to get to the closest document into the graph. You can see how I documented my approach [here](https://github.com/Sirsirious/dissertation/blob/master/Dissertacao_Tiago_Faceroli_Duque_Graph_Based_Approach_for_QA.pdf). However, this approach requires either an already existing set of inter-word relations ([wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) for a simpler approach) or a good time spent annotating word relations.

**Final Words**

However, if you're interested in matching "this document" to "Annex A from e-mail 5". Thats a whooooole other problem. *One that is actually not solved*. You can attempt to use [coreference resolution](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml) for references inside the same paragraph or phrase. But that won't work with different documents (e-mails). If you want to win some notoriety in NLP (actually NLU - Natural Language Understanding), that's a research to delve into.